# fabric-client (node.js) Deploying and Invoking Chaincode on a Network Without CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I replicated the setup from the [`e2e_cli` demo application](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html). I created my own local MSP certificates, and I am able to run some chaincode from the CLI container, as described in the docs.

The next step in developing my application involves tying the transaction execution to multiple client applications that would communicate with the peers and the ordering service.

Is it possible to deploy and invoke chaincode only with the help of the [fabric-client](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node), a.k.a the SDK for Node.js, without the need to set up the "optional" (according to the docs) Fabric CA component? And if yes, is there a code example? All the usage examples I'm able to find on [Github](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/tree/master/examples/balance-transfer) involve calls to the Fabric CA.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a user in node.js SDK without having to enroll it with fabric-ca. Basically you need to have access to the certificate and the corresponding private key for the user, and use the Client.js/createUser() API. See an example at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/balance-transfer/app/helper.js#L297

Comment: So, Jim as I understand it. Is the CA only required if we add new nodes in the network to give out the certificates? Or to put it in another way. CA does what cryptogen does but does it on the fly after requested via the SDK